# Getting Calendar provider Events and Attendees using Loader Manager

Tags: android, android-loadermanager

Step#1: I am getting List of events Ids from calendar provider for a specific day using Loader 1.

Step#2: For the list of events from Step#1 retrieving list of attendees using loader 2

Step#3: Created a custom Adapter to render the results.

The problem is before loader #1 gets finished view/fragment gets displayed with blank screen

I would like to know wether the above design approach i am following is correct or not? What is the best way to load this kind of data?

Answer (score 0):

I created a custom loader. Which will get data from Calendar provider.

Then with Cutom array adapter i am populating the list. The issue i was facing was

once i get the calendar data, List fragment was still blank.

Solution: onLoadFinished method you need to set the adapter data (List)

In the adapter i used the following method to iterate through the list and add individual object to the List view.

The issue is, i was trying to add all the objects at once to the list view. but getView method in the Custom adapter was not getting invoked. So you need to add individual objects to the list view.

public void setMyList(List objects) {

```
    for(MyObject object:objects){
        this.add(object);
    }
}
```